# How do I put this long formula as my data validation list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016, vba

How do I put this long formula as my data validation list?

> =IF(P2="SUML01", SUML01, IF(P2="SUML02", SUML02, IF(P2="SUML03", SUML03, IF(P2="SUML04", SUML04, IF(P2="SUML05", SUML05,
>   IF(P2="SUML06", SUML06, IF(P2="SUML07", SUML07, IF(P2="SUML08",
>   SUML08, IF(P2="SUML09", SUML09, IF(P2="SUML10", SUML10,
>   IF(P2="SUML11", SUML11, IF(P2="SUML12", SUML12, IF(P2="SUML13",
>   SUML13, IF(P2="NAAL01", NAAL01, IF(P2="NAAL02", NAAL02,
>   IF(P2="EMAL01", EMAL01, IF(P2="ACTL1", ACTL1, IF(P2="ACTL2", ACTL2,
>   IF(P2="OUTL01", OUTL01, IF(P2="OUTL02", OUTL02, IF(P2="OUTL03",
>   OUTL03, IF(P2="OUTL04", OUTL04, IF(P2="OUTL05", OUTL05,
>   IF(P2="OUTL06", OUTL06, IF(P2="OUTL07", OUTL07, IF(P2="OUTL08",
>   OUTL08, IF(P2="RELL01", RELL01, IF(P2="RELL02", RELL02,
>   IF(P2="SLAL01", SLAL03,""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

I tried typing it manually or copy pasting it but the data validation list didn't allow it.
Note that I am using Excel 2016 Pro Plus.

Comment: Would `=INDIRECT(P2)` work?  Oops - just noticed the last statement which tests for "SLAL01" but uses `SLAL03`, so the `INDIRECT` won't work.

Comment: when trying to copy your fomrula, I got an error, you are missing one closing `)`. since your are using Excel 2016, why not use the `SWITCH` Function ?

Comment: @Paul Nikkolai Arma  one important thing (found out on my Excel 2010, you need to check on your 2016 version), the Validation List Formula will not accept strings length of more than 255 characters. Checking the length of your formula here, it's 722 characters

Comment: @Paul Nikkolai Arma see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In case that the last `IF(P2="SLAL01", SLAL03,` is not an error, you can use the following formula inside your Data Validation List Formula bar:

```
=IF($P$2="SLAL1",SLAL3,INDIRECT($P$2))
```

See image below how I've writte it into P4 cell:

[image]

The selection of Cell P4 once P2 is **SLAL01** (the Name Range **SLAL03**)

[image]

The selection of Cell P4 once P2 is **SUML01** (the Name Range **SUML01**)

[image]

In case the last `IF(P2="SLAL01", SLAL03,` is a Typo, and you meant `IF(P2="SLAL01", SLAL01,` then the formula is simplier:

```
 =INDIRECT($P$2)
```

Comment: yes, the SLAL03 is a typo and your indirect perfectly works! thank you soooooo much! :)

Comment: @Paul-Nikkolai-Arma mark as answer (put a v next to my answer here )